# Error when trying to start the agar server via Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, npm, server

I'm trying to start the agar server(https://github.com/Wizya/HerokuAgarServer)
But when I enter the `npm start` command, I get an error[image]

`npm install` did not solve the problem

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module 'figlet'`

Comment: Can you try `npm install figlet`?